# Doubts about BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

Hi I am using the following code

```
private boolean statusUSB = false;

private final BroadcastReceiver usbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action != null) {

            switch (action) {
                case UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED:
                    final UsbDevice detDevice = (UsbDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    final String detMsg="Device DEtached";
                    statusUSB = false;
                    Toast.makeText(context, "USB Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED:
                case UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED:
                    final UsbDevice attDevice = (UsbDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    final String attMsg="Device atached";
                    statusUSB = true;
                    Toast.makeText(context, "USB Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

To detect when the USB port is connected or disconnected, apart from that I have also inserted a flag:

```
statusUSB 

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.main, menu );

    if (statusUSB == true){
        // Opcion1
    }
    if (statusUSB == false){
        //Opcion2
    }

    return true;
}
```

The fact is that the Android detects both conditions when the USB port is connected and disconnected, but the flag does not change or I can not read this value in my menu, I am doing well? or there is another way to feed this flag?

Comment: Show some more complete code.

Comment: You mean, the data is received in your BroadcastReceiver but the menu is not updated?

Answer (score 1):

`onCreateOptionsMenu()` is only called once, the first time the options menu is displayed. You are trying to update the Menu state here, which won't work.

To update the menu every time it is displayed, you should use `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu)`.

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    if (statusUSB == true){
        // Update menu
    }
    if (statusUSB == false){
        // Update menu
    }
}
```